# Allowing input of Unicode escapes as command line arguments

Tags: python, linux, unicode

I have a fairly simple program which grabs values from a file on the filesystem and allows the user to format them and print them. An average invocation of the script looks like this:

```
get-amazing-temperature -c 0 --format "%.2f"
```

I use that `format` argument to format the value so that users of the script can format numbers in clever, creative ways. The problem comes, of course, when they want to have a custom format with the degrees (U+00B0) symbol.

I'm using `argparse` underneath the hood. When I try something like this:

```
get-amazing-temperature -c 0 --format '%.2f\u00B0'
```

...the string literal is printed:

```
36\u00B0
```

How can I allow in unicode literals in command line arguments? I'll only be running this script on Linux/Unix machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you process the argument containing the format string, you could decode it with the "unicode-escape" codec.  This will convert unicode escapes to their corresponding characters:

```
>>> print x
%.2f\u00B0
>>> print x.decode('unicode-escape')
%.2f°
```